# Download GitHub files in directories

Tags: c#, github

I have this function in my script:

```
private void DownloadFile(string file, string location)
        {
            var githubToken = "[token]";
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.github.com/repos/[owner]/[repo]/contents/" + file);
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, string.Concat("token ", githubToken));
            request.Accept = "application/vnd.github.v3.raw";
            request.UserAgent = "useragent";
            try
            {
                using (var response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    var encoding = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8;
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
                    {
                        /*using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(location))
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                            sw.Close();
                        }*/
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(location))
                        {
                            byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd());
                            fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex + "\n " + file);
            }
        }
```

So downloading a single file in the root directory like repo/text.txt, this works great! But when I want to download the file in files/file1.rar, that doesn't work. It gives me an 403 or 404. Can somebody explain why this is, and how to download files from a directory (the repository is private, therefore the large chunk of code)

Comment: While I don't think it's the immediate cause, a rar file would cause an issue with your current code as you're expecting it to be text. There's no need to decode it to text and then re-encode it - just create the output stream and use `Stream.CopyTo` to copy `response.GetResponseStream()` to that...

Comment: Ah yes ofcourse, but the foremost problem for the moment is that it gives an error at the var request = (HttpWebRequest)... line, but i will remember that, thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the error is actually on that line, I trust you are substituting the [owner] and [repo] with real values? Confused if it is that line as you said you managed to download text files.

Comment: Yes i have now found out the error itself, but no idea of how to fix it. You see it returns 403: Forbidden, and I looked it up and it seems like you cannot download files larger than 1 MB without even more freaking code! Like OMG just let me please xD

Comment: Yer I wonder if you can grab the JSON with `Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json` then pick out the the raw download URL from that.